# How to make multiple if statements run faster in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas dataframe

```
 Code      Sum      Quantity
 0         -12      0
 1          23      0
 2         -10      0
 3         -12      0
 4         100      0
 5         102      201
 6          34      0
 7         -34      0
 8         -23      0
 9         100      0
 10        100      0
 11        102      300
 12        -23       0
 13        -25       0
 14        100      123
 15        167      167
```

My desired dataframe is

```
Code      Sum      Quantity    new_sum
0         -12      0          -12
1          23      0           23
2         -10      0          -10
3         -12      0          -12
4         100      0           0
5         102      201         202 
6          34      0           34
7         -34      0          -34
8         -23      0          -23
9         100      0           0
10        100      0           0
11        102      300         302
12        -23       0          -23
13        -25       0          -25
14        100      123         100 
15        167      167         167
```

Logic is:

First I will check for non zero values in the *quantity* column. In the above sample data we got the first non zero occurance of *quantity* at index 4, which is 201. Then I want to add column *sum* till I get negative value in the row.

I have written a code, which uses nested `if` statements.However,it takes lot of time to execute the code because of multiple if's and row wise comparison.

```
current_stock = 0
for i in range(len(test)):
    if(test['Quantity'][i] != 0):
        current_stock = test['Sum'][i]
        if(test['Sum'][i-1] > 0):
            current_stock = current_stock + test['Sum'][i-1]
            test['new_sum'][i-1] = 0
            if(test['Sum'][i-2] > 0):
                current_stock = current_stock + test['Sum'][i-2]
                test['new_sum'][i-2] = 0
                if(test['Sum'][i-3] > 0):
                    current_stock = current_stock + test['Sum'][i-3]
                    test['new_sum'][i-3] = 0
                else:
                    test['new_sum'][i] = current_stock
            else:
                test['new_sum'][i] = current_stock
        else:
            test['new_sum'][i] = current_stock
    else:
        test['new_sum'][i] =  test['Sum'][i]
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Your test code refers to a column called `'stock_volume'` but no such column exists. When you say "Then I want to add column sum till I get positive values in the row above index 4", what does that mean? If you add 100 to 0, you get 100 which is positive; not 202. Should they perhaps be greater than the value in `'Quantity'`? And in your code, it looks like you only check the 3 previous rows, but nothing about that appears in your logic.

Comment: @fuglede Edited the question

Comment: Thanks; I still don't follow why you only check 3 rows in your own example, when that does not appear to be part of the logic, and in the answer below that restriction is removed.

Comment: It's not the `if`s, it's the `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at three solutions and provide performance comparisons at the end.

One approach that tries to stay close to pandas would be the following:

```
def f1(df):
    # Group together the elements of df.Sum that might have to be added
    pos_groups = (df.Sum <= 0).cumsum()
    pos_groups[df.Sum <= 0] = -1
    # Create the new column and populate it with what is in df.Sum
    df['new_sum'] = df.Sum
    # Find the indices of the new column that need to be calculated as a sum
    indices = df[df.Quantity > 0].index
    for i in indices:
        # Find the relevant group of positive integers to be summed, ensuring
        # that we only consider those that come /before/ the one to be calculated
        group = pos_groups[:i+1] == pos_groups[i]
        # Zero out all the elements that will be part of the sum
        df.new_sum[:i+1][group] = 0
        # Calculate the actual sum and store that
        df.new_sum[i] = df.Sum[:i+1][group].sum()

f1(df)
```

One place where there's possibly room for improvement would be in `pos_groups[:i+1] == pos_groups[i]` which checks all `i+1` elements when, depending on what your data looks like, it could probably get away with checking a fraction of those. However, chances are this is still more efficient in practice. If not, you may want to iterate by hand to find the groups:

```
def f2(sums, quantities):
    new_sums = np.copy(sums)
    indices = np.where(quantities > 0)[0]
    for i in indices:
        a = i
        while sums[a] > 0:
            s = new_sums[a]
            new_sums[a] = 0
            new_sums[i] += s
            a -= 1
    return new_sums

df['new_sum'] = f2(df.Sum.values, df.Quantity.values)
```

Finally, depending once again on what your data looks like, there is a decent chance that the latter approach can be improved using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/):

```
from numba import jit
f3 = jit(f2)
df['new_sum'] = f3(df.Sum.values, df.Quantity.values)
```

For the data provided in the question (which might very well be too small to provide a proper picture) the performance tests looks as follows:

```
In [13]: %timeit f1(df)
5.32 ms ± 77.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit df['new_sum'] = f2(df.Sum.values, df.Quantity.values)
190 µs ± 5.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each

In [18]: %timeit df['new_sum'] = f3(df.Sum.values, df.Quantity.values)
178 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Here, most of the time is spent on updating the data frame. If the data were 1000 times larger, the Numba solution would end up being a clear winner:

```
In [28]: df_large = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index()

In [29]: %timeit f1(df_large)
5.82 s ± 63.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [30]: %timeit df_large['new_sum'] = f2(df_large.Sum.values, df_large.Quantity.values)
6.27 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit df_large['new_sum'] = f3(df_large.Sum.values, df_large.Quantity.values)
215 µs ± 5.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @fudlede Thank you so much for your response. Can we include one more condition in above logic. e.g quantity is non zero for consecutive rows then I do not want to add numbers.I want to add them as it is in `new_sum` column. I have edited the question.

Comment: What would happen if the final -25 were a 25 instead?

Comment: Had it been 25 and corresponding `Quantity` column is not zero `new_sum` will be `25`,if it is `0` then it will get added to `100`

Comment: Any solution for above scenario?